# Efficient validation

Tags: python, string, validation

I am trying to combine two forms of validation to check the sequence of characters in a string. Struggling to add the second, not sure where I am going wrong, could you please help??

```
def passwordnumbercheck(password):
    numberCheck = [];
    for i in password:
        numberCheck.append(i.isnumeric());
    if numberCheck == [False, False, True, False]:
        return True;
        print ("this is a valid password")
    else:
        return False;
        print ("this is invalid")


def passwordlettercheck(password):
    letterCheck = [];
    for i in password:
        letterCheck.append(i.isalpha());
    if letterCheck == [True, True, False, True]:
        return True;
        passwordnumbercheck (password)
    else:
        return False;
        print("this is not a valid password")



password = input("enter a valid password, it must be a letter, a letter, a number and a letter ")
passwordlettercheck (password)
passwordnumbercheck (password)
```

Comment: why print after return :(

Comment: should be        print ("this is invalid") return False;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use re module.

```
>>> password = input("enter a valid password, it must be a letter, a letter, a number and a letter ")
>>> password = input("enter a valid password, it must be a letter, a letter, a number and a letter :\n")
enter a valid password, it must be a letter, a letter, a number and a letter : 
ll7l
>>> def check(passw):
        if re.match(r'^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z]$', passw):
            print('valid password')
        else:
            print('Invalid password')


>>> check(password)
valid password
>>> password = input("enter a valid password, it must be a letter, a letter, a number and a letter :\n")
enter a valid password, it must be a letter, a letter, a number and a letter :
7u6y
>>> check(password)
Invalid password
```